# Do Alamofire threads work even another view controller on the screen ? ios

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire and i am not able to test this condition since the network is really fast around me

When i call Alamofire from one viewController, and user moves to another viewController, does the Alamofire threads continues execution or stops ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alamofire requests from the first view controller will continue to run asynchronously unless you manually cancel them.

By the way, you can use the [Network Link Conditioner](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/) to simulate suboptimal networking conditions and confirm this behavior.